# Python Tkinter property tax GUI

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface, tkinter

I have gotten everything to show up in the gui but now I can't get the tax conversion to show up correctly.

Here is my code after working through it some more. I have now made two stringvar objects for each label. However, it can't seem to convert the property tax to a float.

The property tax should be $0.75 for each $100 of the assessment value.

Therefore, if you were to enter 250000 for property value, it would need to return an assessment value of 150000 and a property tax value of 1125.

```
    import tkinter


def main():
    my_gui = PropertyTaxGUI()

class PropertyTaxGUI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.third_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        #create widgets for the top frame
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,
                                          text='Enter the property value: $')
        self.prop_value = tkinter.Entry(self.top_frame,
                                        width=10)

        #pack the top frame's widgets
        self.prompt_label.pack(side='left')
        self.prop_value.pack(side='left')

        #create widgets for the middle frame
        self.assess_val = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame,
                                        text='Assessment Value: $')

        #need a stringvar object to associate with an output label
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        #create a label and associate it with the stringvar object
        self.assess_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame,
                                          textvariable=self.value)

        #pack the middle frame's widgets
        self.assess_val.pack(side='left')
        self.assess_label.pack(side='left')

        #create the widgets for the third frame
        self.prop_tax = tkinter.Label(self.third_frame,
                                      text='Property Tax: $')

        #need a stringvar object to associate witih second output label
        self.value2 = tkinter.StringVar()

        #create a label and associate it with the stringvar object
        self.prop_tax_val = tkinter.Label(self.third_frame,
                                          textvariable=self.value2)

        #pack the third frame's widgets
        self.prop_tax.pack(side='left')
        self.prop_tax_val.pack(side='left')

        #create the button widgets for the bottom frame
        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                          text='Calculate',
                                          command=self.calc_button_event)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                          text='Quit',
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack the buttons
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.third_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #enter the tkinter main loop
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc_button_event(self):
        self.calculate()
        self.taxCalc()


    def calculate(self):
        propVal = float(self.prop_value.get())

        assessVal = propVal*0.6

        self.value.set(assessVal)

    def taxCalc(self):

        assessVal = float(self.value2.get())

        assessTax = assessVal*0.0075

        self.value2.set(assessTax)



main()
```

Comment: I believe you need to add the tkinter.Canvas() with the height and width dimensions. What you have now is valid, but not within the canvas.

Comment: I have edited now and came up with another problem. Could you take a look at my code again please?

Comment: Homework: Convert your title to a round question sentence and I will change my downvote to an up.

Comment: already figured it out. No need to be so pretentious. Just asking for a little push, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is have only one function that computes the total property tax. You are using two methods now, only one of which appears to be called. Try this code:

```
import tkinter

class PropertyTaxGUI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.third_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        #create widgets for the top frame
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,
                                      text='Enter the property value: $')
        self.prop_value = tkinter.Entry(self.top_frame,
                                    width=10)
        #pack the top frame's widgets
        self.prompt_label.pack(side='left')
        self.prop_value.pack(side='left')

        #create widgets for the middle frame
        self.assess_val = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame,
                                    text='Assessment Value: $')

        #need a stringvar object to associate with an output label
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        #create a label and associate it with the stringvar object
        self.assess_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame,
                                      textvariable=self.value)

        #pack the middle frame's widgets
        self.assess_val.pack(side='left')
        self.assess_label.pack(side='left')

        #create the widgets for the third frame
        self.prop_tax = tkinter.Label(self.third_frame,
                                  text='Property Tax: $')
        self.prop_tax_val = tkinter.Label(self.third_frame,
                                      textvariable=self.value)

        #pack the third frame's widgets
         self.prop_tax.pack(side='left')
         self.prop_tax_val.pack(side='left')

        #create the button widgets for the bottom frame
       self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                      text='Calculate',
                                      command=self.calculate)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                      text='Quit',
                                      command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack the buttons
        self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.third_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #enter the tkinter main loop
        tkinter.mainloop()

   def calculate(self):
       self.propVal = float(self.prop_value.get())

       self.assessVal = self.propVal*0.6

       self.property_tax = (self.propVal//100) * 0.74
       self.value.set(self.property_tax+self.assessVal)



 #create an instance of the class
 my_gui = PropertyTaxGUI()
```

Comment: That's still giving me the same output when the property tax is calculated off of the assessment value. So the assessment value is 60% of the property value, and the property tax is .75 for each $100 of the assessment value. Your code gives .75 of the property value and applies that to both assessment value and property tax value making them the same

Comment: I think I understand the question a bit better. Please see my last edit of calculate().

Comment: No, it's still doing the same thing. Basically, if you enter in 250000 for property value, it needs to return 150000 for assessment value and 1125 for property tax. What you have provided gives back the same thing for propval and proptax